# Google plus moments api adding activity with only url in the target is not showing up in the history tab

Tags: json, google-plus

I created an activity json as following and posting to the google plus moments api

var activity = {
  "type": "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
  "target": {
  "url": "http://www.qontext.com"
  }};

POST is successful but the moment is not shown the history. Authentication is taken care of.
Example url works fine. Can somebody help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the provided target url does not return (html) content that includes the required meta data (http://schema.org/Thing) your inserted element will not show up in the Google+ History (no matter if the Response will be a HTTP 200 or not).

Providing your meta data in the request body (as "result" JSON) does not work either. So you have to ensure that the target url will return HTML that contains the data that you would like to post.

E.g. this can be done via a simple PHP script like this:

```
<?php
    $name   = $_GET["name"];
    $desc   = $_GET["desc"];
echo('
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>emacberry DATA</title>
      </head>
      <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
        <section>Name: <div itemprop="name">'.$name.'</div></section>
        <section>Description: <div itemprop="description">'.$desc.'</div></section>
        <section>
          Thumbnail: <img itemprop="image" src="YOUR_LOGO_HERE"/>
        </section>
      </body>
    </html> 
    ');
?>
```

so then just post

```
{
    "type":"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
    "target":{
        "url":"http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_SCRIPT.PHP?name=A_NAME&desc=A_DESC"
    }
}
```

by doing so you activity will be added to the Google+ History - but of course that implies interactivity with your server - which can also have some benefits for you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information to be sure, but I would investigate the following:

1) Make sure you have debug=true in the call to the moments API. As in:

`path: '/plus/v1moments/people/me/moments/vault?debug=true'`

and then make sure that you're looking at what comes back to see if there are any errors.

2) Make sure you have schema.org markup in the target page. While usually they're good about getting *something* from the page, it could just be that the page is too complex or large for them to get useful info out of the whole thing.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I tried with debug=true option and able to see 200 OK response with json data. No errors what so ever. But moment is not present in the history.

Comment: What is the JSON data that is returned?

Have you tried adding schema.org markup to the target page?

I'll admit - I'm not sure why this might be happening, and it seems somewhat odd.

Comment: `{
 "kind": "plus#moment",
 "verb": {
  "url": "https://schemas.google.com/AddAction"
 },
 "target": {
  "kind": "plus#itemScope",
  "id": "http://www.qontext.com/",
  "description": "Qontext is an enterprise social collaboration platform that facilitates content sharing and contextual conversations across business applications.",
  "name": "Enterprise Social Collaboration Platform - Qontext.Com",
  "url": "http://www.qontext.com/"
 },
 "result": {
  "kind": "plus#itemScope"
 }
}` this is the response i got when i make rest call with debug=true, no moment present in the history.

Comment: No. I did not have schema.org markup in the target page. I assumed API will try to get something from the URL to be shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I tried submitting your moment:

```
{
  "type":"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
  "target":{
      "url":"http://www.qontext.com"
  }
}
```

to the demo application at:

http://plus-history-examples.appspot.com/client-side-flow/index.html

And the returned response was:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest",
        "message": "Unable to fetch metadata."
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to fetch metadata."
  }
}
```

So I suspect the problem is lack of metadata at http://www.qontext.com

Comment: i got this response intermittently.

Comment: You can try the same request again and you will end up with 500 response. Nice app for testing +1